# Display math and tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode

I'm pretty new to latex and having some trouble.
I have multiple math formulas which I'd like to organize on the page.
i used:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{6cm}p{6cm}}
\[...\] & \[...\]\\
\end{tabular}
```

for this. The problem is the following one: the first formula has different indent depending on its own length (the second one is always on the same place).I guess it's the centering of the displaymath? Is there a way to have the display mode and always the same indent, or should I use another environment?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You can use `$\displaystyle ...$`.  Also, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill Can you make than answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the use of display math mode. Instead you could use inline math and specify `\displaystyle`:

[image]

If your tables only have math content then I would suggest using an `array` as in the last example above. Although, I am not sure why the spacing is slightly different.

### Notes:

- I am *not* advocating the user of vertical rules. They were added just to show where the content is with respect to the borders.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Using \verb|display math mode|

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|}
\[ y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 \] & \[ y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2  \] \\
\end{tabular}

\medskip\noindent
Using \verb|\displaystyle|

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{6cm}|}
$\displaystyle y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2$ & $\displaystyle y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2$ \\
\end{tabular}

\medskip\noindent
Using \verb|\displaystyle| with an \verb|array|:

\noindent
$\begin{array}{|>{$\displaystyle}p{6cm\relax}<{$}|>{$\displaystyle}p{6cm}<{$}|}
 y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 & \displaystyle y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 \\
\end{array}$


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is meant as an addition to Peter's answer.

For a fixed-indentation in your `tabular`, insert an `\hspace*{<len>}` or `\quad`/`\qquad`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{$\displaystyle\qquad}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{|M{6cm}|M{6cm}|}
 y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 & \displaystyle y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 \\
 y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^2 & \displaystyle y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 \\
 y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} \bigl(i^2+i+1\bigr)^2 & \displaystyle y =\sum_{i=0}^{n} i^2 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```